# macOS window closing order

Tags: macos, window-manager

When I have multiple windows open for an application (e.g., Safari), when I close one window, the other window automatically comes into focus, above other application windows that may have been in focus more recently.

How can I disable this? I've tried to illustrate the current situation and desired situation in the below diagram:

[image: Mockup showing: State before, of windows "Safari 1" below "Finder 1" below "Safari 2" with the mouse above the close button of Safari 2. Then state after with Safari 2 closed, showing windows "Safari 1" above "Finder 1". Then the desired state being "Finder 1" above "Safari 1".]

Comment: Actually, for the Windows to be in that configuration to start with, Safari app is already frontmost. There is no avoiding that the next window back in Safari will come to the front. My answer below assumed Finder to be at the front.

Comment: +1 Your diagram is worth a thousand words!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that macOS can be configured like this natively.

Unlike other OSes, macOS is hierarchical in the way that windows 'belong' to an application object. An application is in the 'foreground' (e.g. it's the frontmost object, with focus), and it may have zero, one or more windows open.

If you close a window, you still stay 'in' the application -- even if there are no windows at all.
*(Except for apps that can only have one window, which do quit on close.)*

It is possible to overlay windows of different applications; though normally, switching to an app will bring all its windows to the front.

Assuming that macOS did/could switch to another application whenever you closed one document window -- there are many scenarios where this would be deeply annoying. And if you have other applications open, how is macOS to know which other app you want?

If you want to switch to the Finder, then switch to the Finder. If you want to close a window within an application, then do that. There is Mission Control, the Dock, Command-Tab, the new Stage Manager, and various other ways of managing apps and windows.

Comment: You can easily make windows interleave like that, increasingly since Sierra, the 'all windows to front' you used to get when selecting an app window rather than selecting the app itself from Dock or Cmd/Tab has been failing.

Comment: The first image is not flawed. I can reproduce the behaviour exactly as presented.  But I do agree that the 'desired' behaviour would often be annoying.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The reason I want this behavior is because I have multiple screens with many windows for particular applications and closing one window brings up another from the same application, above a different application window that I'm still using.